# Custom Search and Using Jquery to Hide Fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to hide a field with Jquery on my search form, so that if its a commercial property, there is no 'number of bedrooms' field.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("input:radio#comms").click(function() {
            $("p.bedrooms").hide();
        });
        $("input:radio#sale").click(function() {
            $("p.bedrooms").show();
        });

        $("input:radio#rent").click(function() {
            $("p.bedrooms").show();
        });
    });
});
```

I'm doing this in Wordpress, and the above code seems to work, but my question is - if you hide a field the URL changes to bedrooms=1&location=blackpool  - it defaults to bedrooms = 1. I was wondering if there is a way in a form to have a null value, and if its hidden, don't search on that field at all?

Comment: Note: the bedrooms field will be blank for all commercial properties when creating a new one.

Comment: Maybe `bedrooms=-1`? Though I don't really like the idea of relying on any GET parameters for further code.

Comment: How would you do such code instead for search? I'm open to ideas

Comment: You should probably check server-side if a room can have bedrooms and send that to the client (if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You could always try attaching a .submit() event handler to the form.

I haven't tested or run the code below.

```
// Form will submit after this method runs unless you e.preventDefault();
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
    if ($("p.bedrooms").is(":visible")) {
        // Do somethin
    } else {
        // Bedrooms aren't visible

        // Option 1: empty the value
        $("input[name=bedrooms]").val("")
        /*
           Option 2: remove the input
           Since the form is submitting, it shouldn't matter 
           if you remove an input. Returning to the page should 
           replace the input.
        */
        $("input[name=bedrooms]").remove()
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't a "" value become zero bedrooms though? I've tested the code, I don't think it works. Perhaps the best way is to get rid of bedrooms in the search altogether somehow?

Comment: $("input[name=bedrooms]").remove() should remove the input so that it isn't included in the submit to the action page.